# How to Calculate Nth Weekday of Month (example: Mother's Day)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Just looking for a simple solution to programmatically determine something like Mother's Day (second Sunday in May) or Father's Day (third Sunday in June).

Comment: Why are there so many downvotes on this? I needed this same solution. Glad I found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use Calendar method `nextDate(after:)` passing the `DateComponnets` of the weekday (Sunday = 1) and of the month (May = 5) to find out the first Sunday in May and use the same approach to find out the next Sunday after that date passing just the Sunday weekday component:

```
extension Date {
    var nextSunday: Date {
        return Calendar.current.nextDate(after: self, matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
    }
    var nextMothersDay: Date {
        return Calendar.current.nextDate(after: self, matching: DateComponents(month: 5, weekday: 1), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!.nextSunday
    }
}
```

---

```
Date().nextSunday     // "Jan 7, 2018 at 12:00 AM"
Date().nextMothersDay // "May 13, 2018 at 12:00 AM"
```

Comment: What about other days? This will require a method for each day of the week and some annoying chaining of method calls for dates such as Thanksgiving (4th Thursday).

Comment: As I comment in your answer OP can use your DateComponents example combined with the nextDate method to find out the 4th Thursday for Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 4):

Use `DateComponents`:

```
var dc = DateComponents()
dc.weekday = 1 // Sunday
dc.weekdayOrdinal = 2 // 2nd Sunday
dc.month = 5 // May
dc.year = 2018
let mothersDay = Calendar.current.date(from: dc)

dc.weekday = 5 // Thursday
dc.weekdayOrdinal = 4 // 4th Thursday
dc.month = 11 // November
let thanksgiving = Calendar.current.date(from: dc)
```

Another approach to ensure the next Mother's Day after today, you can do:

```
var dc = DateComponents()
dc.weekday = 1 // Sunday
dc.weekdayOrdinal = 2 // 2nd Sunday
dc.month = 5 // May
let mothersDay = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: dc, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)
```

Comment: Nice approach. The only drawback is the need to find out if the next Mother's Day it is this year or next year.

Comment: @LeoDabus The question is very vague and does not mention "next Mother's Day". Just "Mother's Day". I leave it to the OP to pick the year as needed.

Comment: You can use nextDate with your DateComponents without the year